# Properly encoding Variation Selectors in HTML via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unicode, html-entities

In Unicode a [variation selector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block)) can serve multiple purposes. I use VS15 (`&#65038;`) to prevent browsers (which are *all* bugged) from displaying certain characters as emojis.

I'm required to encode Unicode characters 128 and above as we've discovered issues not only with databases though with browser bugs. The VS15 (variation selector 15: `&#65038;`) does not get properly encoded even with a suggested fix:

**HTML, from the database, *before* being rendered**

```
&#128527;&#65038;
```

The XML encoding function and the character encoding functions used to take *rendered HTML*:

```
function xml_encode(s)
{
 var r = '';
 var skip = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
 {
  if (skip > 0) {skip--;}
  else if (character_code(s, i) > 127)
  {
   r += '&#' + character_code(s, i) + ';';
  }
  else {r += s.charAt(i);}
 }

 return r;
}

function character_code(s, i)
{
 i = i || 0;
 var c = s.charCodeAt(i), hi, low;

 if (0xD800 <= c && c <= 0xDBFF)
 {
  hi = c;
  low = s.charCodeAt(i + 1);
  if (isNaN(low)) {console.log('Error: high surrogate not followed by low surrogate in fixedCharCodeAt()');}
  c = ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
 }

 if (0xDC00 <= c && c <= 0xDFFF) {c = false;}

 return c;
}
```

An example use of this code is when the user switches from visual editing of a page to the XML editing. *How can I ensure that variation selectors are properly encoded?*

Comment: Please note that character 128527 () does not have any variation sequences defined in the Unicode standard. If your browser is displaying  with VS15 differently from  without VS15, it is in fact not Unicode-compliant.

Comment: That's not what "not compliant" means.

Comment: @daxim It does. The Unicode standard explicitly forbids implementations from recognising variation sequences that are not defined as part of the Unicode Character Database, the Ideographic Variation Database, or UTS #51 (Unicode Emoji). +VS-15 must be displayed identically to plain ; otherwise you’re violating the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let s = 'a︎';
// U+0061 ‹a› \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A}
// U+1F60F ‹› \N{SMIRKING FACE}
// U+FE0E ‹◌︎› \N{VARIATION SELECTOR-15}
Array.from(s).map(c => {
    const cp = c.codePointAt(0);
    return cp < 128 ? c : '&#' + cp + ';';
}).join('')
// 'a&#128527;&#65038;'
```

Comment: *Almost* - `character (&#38;#65533;) which displays as &#65533;` after rendered and then taken by this code outputs: `character (&#65533;) which displays as &#65533;`. Could you help me finish this please?

Comment: I don't understand you. What is the input? What is the expected output?

Comment: The code works great except if you're *writing about Unicode*. I'm literally outputting the � character in an article. Unfortunately my XML encoder has been having issues and I really need to update the document.

Comment: Ah, ampersands are code #38; I just realized that and I always write entities using the numeric format. I should have realized that...

Comment: Fixed: `return ((cp == 38 || cp > 127) ? '&#' + cp + ';' : c);`.